# Angular configure environment preserve object keys with quotes

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Unable to preserve quotes on object keys in environment specific configurations when building.  Any ideas?

**(1) environment.dev.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  "http://some.url": "value"
}
```

results in

```
var r = { http://some.url: "value" };
```

**(2) environment.dev.ts**

```
let _environment = {};
_environent["http://some.url"] = "value";
export const environment = _environment;
```

becomes:

```
var r = {};
r.http://some.url = "value";
```

Comment: export const environment = {
  \""http://some.url"\": "value"
}  - is that working?

Comment: @MrCas Unfortunately that isn't valid TS syntax.

Comment: Maybe export const environment = { "\" some.url \"": "value" } ? :))

Comment: You need to escape the double quotes, maybe this will work for you(or something similar :)) ? var expectedUrl = 'http://some.url'

export const environment = {
  "\" + expectedUrl + \"": "value"
}

Answer (score 0):

Seems your are using `environment.ts` not in the correct way, usually it should be like below

```
export const environment = {
  "apiUrl": "http://some.url"
}
```

and in your code you will use it like

```
const url = environment.apiUrl;
```

Comment: Angular is doing dot notation with a bracket notation that in JavaScript can handle reserved words or more correctly when a property name is not a valid identifier.  That is what I am getting at.  Looks like only valid identifier are respected.

Comment: @MatthewCampbell I am not sure what you are trying to resolve, however I would suggest to not swim against the flow of the river, if you want to have different apis also take a look at angular proxy, https://medium.com/better-programming/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d